# How to close MDI Child form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

How do you close a MDI Child form within that child MDI form using a `RETURN` button which will bring me back to the Parent Form? So far i have used the code:

```
if (ActiveMdiChild != null)                 
            ActiveMdiChild.Close();
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried numerous methods but nothing has worked so far
Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you try just Close() ?

Comment: but when you code Close() do i use the forms name? (e.g. frmAddCustomer.Close())

Comment: If you are in the form, just call `this.Close();`  Not sure what `bring me back to the Parent Form` means since in an MDI application, the parent is always active.

Comment: `ParentForm.ActiveMDIChild().Close();`  `MDIForm.Close();`

Comment: That worked thank you so much LarsTech!! As you can prob tell I am still new to C# so things so simple still prove a struggle to me again thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not use:

```
foreach (Form c in this.MdiChildren)
{
   c.Close();
}
```